# Dynamically altering image path for screen size

Tags: jquery

I have a slider built into my web page thats dimensions and ratio alter for different screen sizes, I need the images that I place within this slider to also alter for the same purpose. The code that I have does't seem to be working, I'm a bit of a newbie to jQuery and have pieced it together myself but I think that its essentially quite close to being functional…

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
if($(window).width() < 1600 && $(window).width() > 1440){  
$(".replaceimg").attr("src", $(this).attr("src").split(".").join("_1600."));

}

});
</script>


<img class="replaceimg" src="images/SC.png" alt="image desc" />
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!
M

Comment: I have a working version here: http://www.mdwoodman.co.uk but it only works because I am calling images directly rather than amending the src, which I want to avoid if($(window).width() < 1600 && $(window).width() > 1440){  
     $(".replaceimg").attr("src", "images/SC1600.png");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$(".replaceimg").attr("src", $(this).attr("src").split(".").join("_1600."));
```

to this:

```
$(".replaceimg").attr("src", $(".replaceimg").attr("src").split(".").join("_1600."));
```

Comment: Thanks!!!! I knew I was so close but couldn't figure out for the life of me why it wasn't working :)